# How to make list item have evenly sized height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a list of elements layed out horizontally using `display:inline-block`.

One element is bigger in height than others and it overflows. How can I make it have the same height as others and have it's margin or padding properties to stay within the bounds.

I don't know how to approach this maybe there are two ways:

- How to shrink the bigger element fit with others?
- How to make other elements get bigger to align with the bigger element.

Here is the codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/domBYj

```
  <ul class="topbar-menu">
    <li><a> 1000 points </a></li>
    <li><a class="action-button green"> Get Points </a></li>
    <li><a> Level 10 </a></li>
    <li><a> Buddies </a></li>
  </ul>
```

This is the menu:

```
.topbar-menu {
    display: table;
    margin: 1em auto;
}

.topbar-menu > li {
    background: #333;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}

.topbar-menu a {
    color: #eee;
    display: block;
    padding: 1em 2em;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

This is the bigger element:

```
.topbar-menu .action-button {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0px 10px 5px 0px;
    border-radius: 8px;
}
.green {
    background-color: #82BF56;
    border-bottom: 5px solid #669644;
    text-shadow: 0px -2px #669644;
}
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/yak613/vuo0choq/

Comment: Put your codepen code into your question. If codepen disappeared off the internet, your question will become useless to anyone who comes to this page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly I suggest this bit of code:

```
* {
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

This will make all your height and width declarations not include padding or border in the total real-estate it takes up. As in, it will reduce the height/width and then add on the padding/border. So if you make the declaration `width:200px`, it would always be 200px no matter how much padding/border you add.

Then you need to update your code:

```css
/* Topbar Menu */
* {
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
ul.topbar-menu {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.topbar-menu {
    display: table;
    margin: 1em auto;
}

.topbar-menu > li {
    background: #333;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}

.topbar-menu a {
    color: #eee;
    display: block;
    padding: 1em 2em;
    text-decoration: none;
}

/* Buttons */

.topbar-menu .action-button {
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 8px;
}
.green {
    background-color: #82BF56;
    border-bottom: 5px solid #669644;
    text-shadow: 0px -2px #669644;
}
.topbar-menu a.green {
    padding-bottom: calc(1em - 5px); /* Take 5px off the padding to accomodate the extra border on this particular item */
}

.topbar-menu a.green:hover,
.topbar-menu a.green:focus{
    background: #82BF56;
}

.action-button:active {
    transform: translate(0px, 5px);
    border-bottom: 0px solid;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul class="topbar-menu">
    <li><a> 1000 points </a></li>
    <li><a class="action-button green"> Get Points </a></li>
    <li><a> Level 10 </a></li>
    <li><a> Buddies </a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason why it's larger is because the `border-bottom` on `.green` adds to the `margin-bottom` on the `.action-button`:

```
.green {
  background-color: #82BF56;
  border-bottom: 5px solid #669644;
  text-shadow: 0px -2px #669644;
}
```

You can force the height on all `<li>` to remove the extra padding:

```
.topbar-menu > li {
  background: #333;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  height:50px;
}
```

Or remove the margin from the bottom of the button:

```
.topbar-menu .action-button {
  position: relative;
  max-height: 10px;
  margin: 0px 10px 5px 0px;
  border-radius: 8px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Update your CSS as follows (reducing the bottom margin to 5px):

```
.topbar-menu .action-button {
    position: relative;
    max-height: 10px;
    margin: 0px 10px 5px 0px;
    border-radius: 8px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.topbar-menu .action-button {
    position: relative;
    max-height: 3px;
    margin: 0px 10px 10px 0px;
    border-radius: 8px;
}
.action-button:active {
    transform: translate(0px, 5px);
    border-bottom: 5px solid black;
}
```

The `transform` you make moves it down, pushing the white space (not whitespace `:)` ) down too. Making the `.aciton-button` add a border will negate this.